# Add User role in asp.net with database category

Tags: asp.net, authorization

Sorry for my english i'm french.

Is possible to define role with database?

```
Class user 
string name {get;set}
int cat {get; set}
```

...

```
if (user.cat==1)
role= "Admin"
if (user.cat ==2)
role="members
```

And after restricted access to a controler with

```
[Authorize( Role = "Admin")]
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if i understood it correctly, yes it's possible. check out this [link - Extending ASP.NET Identity 2.0 Roles and Implementation of Role Based Authorization](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/799571/ASP-NET-MVC-Extending-ASP-NET-Identity-Roles)